# ghostscript get exit code 1 only when doing via SSH

Tags: fonts, ssh, ghostscript

When I run this command on my document server directly through the backend it works and creates a printable / correct combined document:

```
cd /docs/processing/ && gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=combo.ps temp1.ps temp2.ps;
```

Now the real task is that I need to SSH to this document server from my other server in order to execute those commands. So I tried this:

```
ssh myuser@myserver "cd /docs/processing/ && gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=combo.ps temp1.ps temp2.ps;"
```

When I do it that way I get an ugly ghostscript error code and it does not work

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.54: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Did some digging and it looks like it has something to do with fonts?
Ghostscript luckily prints out many debug statements when running and I think I found the problem.

When I run locally on my doc server and do not SSH in one of the spots it seems to be looking for the fonts is here (and is successful)

```
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.54/lib/fonts/
```

When I run via SSH it looks to be searching for fonts in a totally different area for some strange reason that I do not know why and so generating all the errors:

```
Can't find (or can't open) font file
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.54/Resource/Font/NimbusMonL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonL-Regu.
Querying operating system for font files...
Didn't find this font on the system!
Unable to substitute for font.
Error: /invalidfont in findfont
```

TLDR: When I SSH in ghostscript is looking for fonts in a different file location and is not finding any fonts which is causing it to error out and fail.

Anyone know how I could go in and tell ghostscript to look in that directory that works for finding fonts? Specifically I guess when I SSH in because that seems to be the difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running Ghostscript as different users in the two situations. Most probably the environment settings for the two users are different, specifically GS_FONTPATH but possibly others as well.

You should examine the two environments. anything in the working one which has GS_ at the start probably needs to be duplicated in the environment of the other user.

Also you might like to try running without -dSAFER, at least as an experiment, as that switch disables reading from 'most' paths (see ghostpdl/gs/doc/use.htm for more information on -dSAFER)